# Setting Image source to BitmapImage throws exception

Tags: c#, xaml, exception, microsoft-metro

I have a simple metro app that allows the user to take a picture and then display that picture in a small thumbnail off to the side, the code block that does this is:

```
ImageEncodingProperties imageProp = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
var photoStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await mediaCaptureManager.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(imageProp, photoStream);
var bmpImg = new BitmapImage();
await bmpImg.SetSourceAsync(photoStream);
imageOne.Source = bmpImg;
```

This throws an exception on the line:

```
await bmpImg.SetSourceAsync(photoStream);
```

Saying:

```
The component could not be found
```

MSDN documents show that you're supposed to use `SetSourceAsync` when setting a `BitmapImage` source, but I have no idea why this isn't working. Any ideas?